# Get List of servers part of AD group

Tags: active-directory

How is it possible to get the list of servers which are assigned to a group or nested group?

> Example:
>
> Group A is assigned to the server A.Group B is assigned to server B.
>
> User1 and user2 is a member of Group12. Then group12 is added as a member of Group A and Group B.

Now I want to get the list of servers user1 and user2 has access.

I am able to retrieve the groups each user is member of. But still I do not know which servers are added to Group12 for example.

**Expected Outcome**

`Some command -GroupID Group12`

**Output** --> ServerA and Server2

`Some command -UserName user1`

**Output** --> ServerA and ServerB

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "assigned to the server"? Is the group added to the Administrator group on the server?

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to get the list of servers that are part of group12. Any command that would result in listing Server A and Server B as result

Comment: What do you mean by "servers that are part of group12"? Are the computer objects for those servers added as members of group12?

Answer (score 2):

From what I could understand from your query, you want to retrieve the members of groups in AD.

You can use the PowerShell cmdlet [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) to query the members of a group, as shown below:

```
# you need to have RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools) module installed
# on the system where you're going to run below cmdlets in PowerShell

Import-Module ActiveDirectory  
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GroupA" -Recursive   # to get members of Group A
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GroupB" -Recursive   # to get members of Group B
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group12" -Recursive  # to get members of Group 12
```